# discord.js - Sending an Embed - TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'execute')

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm bashing my skull on the table trying to figure this out. Would love some help or suggestions if anyone has any. I'm currently just trying to push out a very simple test embed but am having 0 luck. I'm pretty new to JS and very new to the discord API. Any pros out there willing to help me out would be super appreciated!

EDIT: typing "~stoplight" is the action I'm trying to do to populate the embed.

This is the main "bot.js" script

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');

const client = new Discord.Client({ intents: ["GUILDS", "GUILD_MESSAGES"] });

const prefix = '~';

const fs = require('fs');

client.commands = new Discord.Collection();

const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync('./commands/').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));
for(const file of commandFiles){
    const command = require(`./commands/${file}`);
    client.commands.set(command.name, command);
}

client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log('QQ is Online!');
});

//these require a ~ prefix

client.on('messageCreate', messageCreate => {
    if(!messageCreate.content.startsWith(prefix) || messageCreate.author.bot) return;
    
    const args = messageCreate.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/);
    const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();
    
    if(command === 'ping'){
        client.commands.get('ping').execute(messageCreate, args);
    }
    
    else if(command === 'stoplight'){
        client.commands.get('stoplight').execute(messageCreate, args, Discord);
    }
});
```

And this is the super simple test embed I'm trying to push out. Its a separate file called "stoplight.js"

```
module.exports = {
    name: 'test name',
    description: 'test desc',
    
    execute(messageCreate, args, Discord) {
    
        const Embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setColor('#0099ff')
            .setTitle('Test Title')
            .setDescription('Test desc.');
    
        channel.send(Embed);
    
    }
}
```

And finally, this is the error I keep getting...

```
C:\Users\CueQ\Desktop\Discord Bot\bot.js:34
                client.commands.get('stoplight').execute(messageCreate, args, Discord);
                                                ^

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'execute')
    at Client.<anonymous> (C:\Users\CueQ\Desktop\Discord Bot\bot.js:34:35)
    at Client.emit (node:events:539:35)
    at MessageCreateAction.handle (C:\Users\CueQ\Desktop\Discord Bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\actions\MessageCreate.js:26:14)
    at Object.module.exports [as MESSAGE_CREATE] (C:\Users\CueQ\Desktop\Discord Bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\handlers\MESSAGE_CREATE.js:4:32)
    at WebSocketManager.handlePacket (C:\Users\CueQ\Desktop\Discord Bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketManager.js:351:31)
    at WebSocketShard.onPacket (C:\Users\CueQ\Desktop\Discord Bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:444:22)
    at WebSocketShard.onMessage (C:\Users\CueQ\Desktop\Discord Bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:301:10)
    at WebSocket.onMessage (C:\Users\CueQ\Desktop\Discord Bot\node_modules\discord.js\node_modules\ws\lib\event-target.js:199:18)
    at WebSocket.emit (node:events:527:28)
    at Receiver.receiverOnMessage (C:\Users\CueQ\Desktop\Discord Bot\node_modules\discord.js\node_modules\ws\lib\websocket.js:1160:20)
```

The error comes after typing "~stoplight" on the server. "~ping" works just dandy. So I'm at a loss...
Thanks in advance~

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Did you want ```stoplight``` or ```spotlight```?

Comment: Stoplight! Sorry, sometimes the dyslexia works against me. I corrected it. Thank you, haha. Sadly that was not the fix, however.

Comment: Is `execute` a custom function you've made? If so,  the error is telling you that whatever you get by doing `Collection.get()` does not have a method called `execute`.

Comment: Do you happen to have a ```stoplight.js```  (or whatever the js file is associated with ```stoplight```?

Comment: Hmm. The "~ping" command uses the same execute function and it works fine. Is there a reason one would work when the other doesn't?

Comment: Yes ewong, the second codeblock is stoplight.js

Comment: Your ```command.name``` is ```test name```.  Shouldn't that be ```stoplight```?

Comment: That did it actually. Fixing that moved us on to a different error that was caused by a mistype on my end, so yay for that too. However I'm now at ANOTHER error saying 
`DiscordAPIError: Cannot send an empty message`

Answer (score 0):

Okay so it was a collection of issues but I got there. Thanks to Ewong for putting me on the right path.

Issue 1: `command.name` was a test name. Switched it to `stoplight`

Issue 2: Misspelled `description`. Classic

Issue 3: `channel.send(Embed);` in `spotlight.js` is old syntax. Changed it to `messageCreate.channel.send({ embeds: [Embed] });`

The `bot.js` code stayed the same, the new `stoplight.js` code looks like this.

```
module.exports = {
    name: 'stoplight',
    description: 'test desc',
    
    execute(messageCreate, args, Discord) {
    
        const Embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setColor('#0099ff')
            .setTitle('Test Title')
            .setDescription('Test desc.');
    
        messageCreate.channel.send({ embeds: [Embed] });
    
    }
}
```

Thanks for the help everyone~